# cannot open visual basic 6.0 project due to component 'msconctl.ocx' not registered error

Tags: vb6

I have a project in visual basic 6.0 with an error message that,
 'msconctl.ocx' or one of its dependencies not correctly registered: 
a file is missing or invalid.

Can't figure out what is the problem, 
i am also getting an error:- object or with block variable.
please help?
thanks

Comment: Please edit and elaborate more on the nature of the problem. What have you tried so far? Have you searched the web with exact error message? At this point your question has to be closed because of low quality. Sorry.

Comment: i tried reinstalling vb...but to no avail

Comment: whichever project i am opening on vb6 i am getting the above 2 errors on startup. whereas when i searched in vb6 folder i have the file 'msconctl.ocx'

Comment: I honestly have no idea what the problem is. But since VB 6 is pretty ancient in computer terms, it might be OS compatibility. If you're using modern Windows (like 7, 8 or 10) it may simply be too old.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm pretty sure that you are talking about mscomctl.ocx (not msconctl.ocx), the Microsoft Common Control library, which is where you get all the common controls (text box, label, etc.) used in VB6.  If you don't have this registered properly, VB6 won't run.

You haven't told us if you're using a 64-bit version of Windows or not.  This makes a difference.  In any case, you should be able to work out a solution by reading [This](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/mscomctlocx-dependency-error-attempting-to-install/f96acaa3-90d7-437a-a9cc-9130eb17fdb4?auth=1).

Answer (score 0):

MSComCtl.OCX was in 2012 modified in such a way that it became in-compatibable with legacy VB6 applications.  MSComCtl.OCX prior to that was working fine.  I ran into this and the only alternative left to me was to remove the control from the project ( in my case a Status Bar ) and use a Label field to cover the duties of the Status Bar.  Once I was upgraded to a .Net Codebase I re-introduced the .Net Status Bar and things were back to normal.       You probably didn't do anything wrong...its just a change to MSCOMCTL.OCX that once applied to your machine will break old VB6 projects that use that control.  If you run or attempt to compile the app, VB6 should point you to the line(s) of code encountering the error.   That will tell you which control is being victimized.  Consider removing the control, and also the reference to MSComCtl, and creating workarounds.   Sorry...just another nail in the VB6 coffin.  I hate it but can't prevent it.     Hope this helps.